# perl error: Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: perl

I get the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at checkfornewfiles.pl line 34.
```

when attempting to run the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#Author: mimo
#Date 3/2015
#Purpose: monitor directory for new files...

AscertainStatus();
        ######### start of subroutine ########
sub AscertainStatus {
    my $DIR= "test2";

    ####### open handler #############
    opendir (HAN1, "$DIR") || die "Problem: $!";

    ########## assign theoutput of HAN1 to array1 ##########
    my @array1= readdir(HAN1);

    ######## adding some logic #########

    if ("$#array1" > 1) {   #### if files exists (more than 1) in the directory #######
            for (my $i=0; $i<2; $i++) {shift @array1;}      ####### for i in position 0 (which is the . position) loop twice and add one (the position ..) get rid of them #######
            MailNewFiles(@array1);
    }       else { print "No New Files\n";}

}

sub MailNewFiles {
    $mail= "sendmail";

    open ($mail, "| /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t" ) ||die "errors with sendmail $!"; # open handler and pipe it to sendmail
    print $mail <<"EOF";    #print till the end of fiEOF
    From: "user";
    To: "root";
    Subject: "New Files Found";

    foreach (@_) {print $mail "new file found:\n $_\n";}
EOF
    close($mail);
}

#End
```

I am new to perl and I don't know what's going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: This is why I left SO long ago and didn't return-it has become a breeding ground for arrogance. They could have answered your question without viciously scolding you especially since you actually stated you were new to the language. But SO wants to be Wikipedia now and has a stick so far up its "ask" that it has become something I am ashamed to be a part of.  Nobody dare ask a question without being possibly humiliated, shamed, reprimanded, and browbeaten before and *if* an actually answer is even given. I'm sorry that I am one of the ones that remembers how SO was before "they" arrived.

Answer (score 5):

A few suggestions:

- Perl isn't C. Your main program loop shouldn't be a declared subroutine which you then execute. Eliminate the `AscertainStatus` subroutine.
- Always, always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.
- Indent correctly. It makes it much easier for people to read your code and help analyze what you did wrong.
- Use a more modern Perl coding style. Perl is an old language, and over the years new coding style and techniques have been developed to help you eliminate basic errors and help others read your code.
- Don't use system commands when there are Perl modules that can do this for you in a more standard way, and probably do better error checking. Perl comes with the [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) that handles mail communication for you. Use that.

The error `Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string` is exactly what it says. You are attempting to use a value of a variable that hasn't been set. In this case, the variable is the `@_` variable in your `foreach` statement. Your `foreach` isn't a true `foreach`, but part of your `print` statement since your `EOF` is ***after*** your `for` statement. This looks like an error.

Also, what is the value of `@_`? This variable contains a list of values that have been passed to your subroutine. If none are passed, it will be undefined. Even if `@_` is undefined, `foreach (undef)` will simply skip the loop. However, since `foreach (@_) {` is a string to print, your Perl program will crash without `@_` being defined.

If you remove the `-w` from `#!/usr/bin/perl`, your program will actually "*work*" (Note the quotes), and you'll see that your `foreach` will literally print.

I do not recommend you not to use warnings which is what `-w` does. In fact, I recommend you `use warnings;` rather than `-w`. However, in this case, it might help you see your error.

Answer (score 0):

You have `EOF` after the line with `foreach`. It contains `$_` which is interpolated here but `$_` is not initialized yet because it is not in `foreach` loop. It is not code but just text. Move EOF before `foreach`.

But probably you would like

```
sub MailNewFiles {
    $mail= "sendmail";

    open ($mail, "| /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t" ) ||die "errors with sendmail $!"; # open handler and pipe it to sendmail
    local $"="\n"; # " make syntax highlight happy
    print $mail <<"EOF";    #print till the end of fiEOF
From: "user";
To: "root";
Subject: "New Files Found";

New files found:
@_
EOF
    close($mail);
}
```

See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR) for more informations about `$"`.

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
Use of uninitialized value $xxx in ...
```

is very straightforward. When you encounter it, it means that you are using a variable ($xxx) in any way, but that the variable has not ever been initialized.

Sometimes, adding an initialization command at the start of you code is enough :

```
my $str = '';
my $num = 0;
```

Sometimes, your algorithm is wrong, or you just mistyped your variable, like in :

```
my $foo = 'foo';
my $bar = $ffo . 'bar'; # << There is a warning on this line
                        # << because you made a mistake on $foo ($ffo)
```